# Difference between log.info(“dsasdds {}”, var) and log.info(“dsasdds ” + var)?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Earlier I normally used to use `log.info(“dsasdds ” + var)` to add logs but now, in my new workplace, I see everyone uses `log.info(“dsasdds {}”, var)` way to print logs? Is there any significant difference between these 2 ways on how they work internally?

Comment: The former uses string concatenation, which is easy to use. The later uses parameters, which is easier to edit and format, especially in complex logging statements. There's also performance-related matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the computation of the variable printed in the log.
Supposing that `var.toString()` is relatively expensive and that the `info` level is not enabled for the current logger, by using `log.info(“dsasdds ” + var)` a relatively expensive operation was computed for "nothing" since no logs were written.
With `log.info(“dsasdds {}”, var)`, the `var.toString()` will be invoked only if level of the current logger match with the level requested (`INFO` here).
For expressions, [suppliers (that are lazily evaluated) is also a possibility](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/api.html) :

```
logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", () -> expensiveOperation());
```

Now is a good practice to use systematically lazy evaluated expressions/variables ? 
Not necessarily but that doesn't hurt either in terms of readability in your example.